# XFAFlattener miss some field borders

Tags: pdf, itext, xfa

We are trying to use `XFAFlattener` to flatten a dynamic pdf file.  It seems that some kind of field border has disappeared after flattening. I can upload sample pdf files, before and after flattening, but this website prevents me from uploading files.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In general we do support all kinds of borders.
As far as I know you have already reported the same problem to iText sales department and have attached problem files, right? And you do not like that border around "northern virginia" disappears.
We have already investigated the issue. The border is hidden initially, but then JavaScript due to some conditions changes its state to visible. Here's a JavaScript code from your XFA form:

```
if (xfa.host.version &gt; 8)
    this.ui.textEdit.border.presence = "visible"    
else
    this.ui.textEdit.border.presence = "hidden"
```

The simplest solution would be (if you have possibility/permissions to edit XFA form) to set textEdit element border to visible and remove this part of JavaScript code. If it's not possible we need to have a look in our JavaScript evaluator. Probably it incorrectly handles following statement:

```
if (xfa.host.version & gt; 8)
```